# pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'master_mysql' ([Errno -2] Name does not resolve)")

Tags: flask, docker-compose, flask-sqlalchemy, connection-string, pymysql

Sqlalchemy connection String

```
connection_string = "mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@{host}/{database}?charset=utf8mb4".format(
    user='flask',
    password='AKIAUCBC7I5FNK6CMXMR',
    host='im_master_database:3306',
    database='flask'
)
```

Docker file

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine3.17
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps g++ python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache --update python3 && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN pip3 install PyMySQL
RUN pip3 install pendulum service_identity
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
COPY app/requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY app /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

docker-compose file

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  app:
    image: rapidfort/flaskapp:latest
    container_name: master_app
    restart: always
    labels:
      project: "flask"
    build:
      # build the image from Dockerfile
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      # set database, memcached etc credentials
      DB_HOST: im_master_database
      DB_NAME: flask
      DB_USER: flask
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_PASSWORD: AKIAUCBC7I5FNK6CMXMR
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    depends_on:
      # build those images first
      im_master_database:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      # bind on our 5000 port because most people have 80, 8080 already bound
      - "5000:5000"
  im_master_database:
    container_name: master_mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      # pass volume named mysql-data to mysql container
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    labels:
      project: "flask"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      # credentials
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "AKIAUCBC7I5FNK6CMXMR"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "flask"
      MYSQL_USER: "flask"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "AKIAUCBC7I5FNK6CMXMR"
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", 'mysqladmin', 'ping', '-h', 'master_mysql', '-u', 'flask', '-p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD' ]
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
```

I'm trying to make CI/CD using bitbucket pipeline to AWS-ECS. Pipe line is working fine. I'm pulling the code from docker image by using `docker pull` command. After the version creating in the ECS task definition, found the log saying this

> pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'master_mysql' ([Errno -2] Name does not resolve)")

Comment: If the host is `im_master_database` (SQLAlchemy connection string), the check shouldn't address `master_mysql` (docker-compose file).

Comment: @greybeard I tried even that also, but couldn't help

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

You may be able to solve your problem with using a Docker Network beetwen you containers with "bridge" value on dirver.

https://docs.docker.com/network/

Comment: I tried with bridge still getting same error

Comment: (typo `dirver` -> *driver*?)